# How do I dynamically switch between screens and update the url during search input

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a search input box located in the header. When a user searches and clicks 'enter', an (callback) event is sent out to all of the relevant components that need to react to the search event, including the components that display the search results. My issue is that the header's search box would be visible on other non-search-result screens, and when I search there's no "clean" way of quickly mounting the search-result screens and displaying the search results (I hope it's not too confusing).

So the question is what type of approaches did you take to solve this issue? I was thinking of relying on window location and relying on React-router to load the search-results screen. Then looking at the query parameter (or path that contains the search query) and then kicking off the search.

Update (for clarity):

1. Go to https://www.brainyninja.com/podcast/78b7ab84cf98735fbadb41bb634320f8 The body component name is
2. Now type any other search term in the header's search box and click enter
3. The body component that displays search results is . I need to navigate to the /search route in order to load the  component. The only way I figured out how to do that is by doing a 'window.location = "/search/?query=somesearchquery"' command, which reloads the whole page and negates the point of having an SPA. I don't know of any cleaner way of changing the current body component

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is confusing. Can you clearly mention which search box(Browser or your Component ?) are you referring to?
A screenshot explaining the exact situation would help too.

Comment: updated the description

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer here
https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

Had to use withRouter since my header was not rendered by a React Router.

```
Now, what if the Register component wasn’t being rendered by React Router? (Meaning, we’re not passing Register as a component prop to a Route. Instead, we’re just rendering it ourselves like <Register />). If it’s not rendered by React Router, then we won’t have access to history.push. The team thought of this use case so React Router comes with a handy HOC called withRouter. Going back to our Register code above, by adding withRouter, it would look like this

import {
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

class Register extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (user) => {
    saveUser(user).then(() =>
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
    ))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Register)
```